# Why dynamodb is not throttled even consumed RCU exceeds provisioned RCU?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a dynamodb table and it receives a high query request no its GSI. When I observe the metrics for `ConsumedReaceCapacityUnit`, `ReadThrottleEvents` and `ProvisionedReadCapapcityUnits` as show in below screenshot. I can see the consumed RCI is far more than provisioned one. But I can't see events are throttled.

How does the throttled metrics work in this case? why is my table not throttled?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DynamoDB has [burst capacity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ProvisionedThroughput.html#ProvisionedThroughput.Throttling):

> DynamoDB uses **burst capacity** to accommodate reads or writes in excess of your table's throughput settings. With burst capacity, unexpected read or write requests can succeed where they otherwise would be throttled.

Thus in your case, it seams burst took place for short time.